# Reflectively set field of struct that was passed in as interface{}

Tags: go, reflection

The following works fine:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    MyField int32
}

func SetReflectConcrete(obj *MyStruct, fieldName string, newValue interface{}) {
    objElem := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    field := objElem.FieldByName(fieldName)
    field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(newValue))
}

func main() {
    myStruct := MyStruct{123}
    SetReflectConcrete(myStruct, "MyField", int32{1234})
}
```

How can I make a variant of the `SetReflect` function that works on any struct? All my attempts so far have failed. The signature would be something like this:

```
func SetReflectInterface(obj interface{}, fieldName string, newValue interface{})
```

And is this even possible, when calling it like

```
SetReflectInterface(myStruct, "MyField", int32{1234})
```

or would it have to be called like

```
SetReflectInterface(&myStruct, "MyField", int32{1234})
```

(After all, `interface{}` has a pointer to the struct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the argument as type `interface{}` as you noted.  Pass a pointer to the struct as in the last code snippet.

```
func SetReflectConcrete(obj interface{}, fieldName string, newValue interface{}) {
    objElem := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    field := objElem.FieldByName(fieldName)
    field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(newValue))
}

myStruct := MyStruct{123}
SetReflectConcrete(&myStruct, "MyField", int32(1234))
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aIm702JtvKM).

The reflect value must be addressable to set a field. The value will not be addressable if created directly from a struct.

Comment: How embarrassing - I had actually tried this function - my mistake was to pass not a pointer to struct, but a pointer to interface{} of that struct... Thanks!